# How do you create a Rust Quick XML reader from either a file or URL?

Tags: rust

I have the following code using the quick_xml library:

```rust
use quick_xml::Reader;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::BufReader;

/// Returns an XML stream either from a file or a URL.
fn get_xml_stream(source: &str) -> Result<Reader<impl BufRead>, Error> {
    let local_path = Path::new(source);

    // Try to read a local file first.
    if local_path.is_file() {
        let reader =
            Reader::from_file(source).context(format!("couldn't read file {:?}", source))?;
        return Ok(reader);
    }
    // Try to fetch a remote file.
    let response = reqwest::get(source).context(format!(
        "File not found and failed fetching from remote URL {}",
        source
    ))?;
    if !response.status().is_success() {
        return Err(format_err!("XML download failed with {:#?}", response));
    }

    Ok(Reader::from_reader(BufReader::new(response)))
}
```

The return type is dynamic: a Reader that either has data from a file or response body.

Compilation error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:225:43
    |
225 |     Ok(Reader::from_reader(BufReader::new(response)))
    |                                           ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::fs::File`, found struct `reqwest::response::Response`
    |
    = note: expected type `std::fs::File`
               found type `reqwest::response::Response`
```

The compiler thinks we always want to read from a file, but this is a response stream here. How can I tell the compiler to accept both types of buffered readers in the XML reader?

Comment: Attempt 1: use dyn instead of impl: `fn get_xml_stream(source: &str) -> Result<Reader<dyn BufRead>, Error> {`. Does not work: `error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::io::BufRead + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time`. How can I amke the size known? Let's try a box next.

Comment: Attempt 2: use `fn get_xml_stream(source: &str) -> Result<Reader<Box<dyn BufRead>>, Error> {`. Does not work because I cannot get the Box into the XML reader. How would I get a box into a reader when I create it from a file name?

Comment: Attempt 3: use the Box around the whole Reader: `fn get_xml_stream(source: &str) -> Result<Box<Reader<dyn BufRead>>, Error> {`. Does not work because we have the same error message as in attempt 1.

Comment: Attempt 4: use a generic type: `fn get_xml_stream<B: BufRead>(source: &str) -> Result<Reader<B>, Error> {`. Does not work because the compiler throws 4 errors, one for the caller now "cannot infer type for `B`".

Comment: Attempt 5: trying to use BufReader directly which is a concrete type: `fn get_xml_stream(source: &str) -> Result<Reader<BufReader<dyn Read>>, Error> {`. But that just pushes the error to the next level, now we have the same problem with the dynamic read. How can I specify a concrete type instead of Read?

Comment: Attempt 6: instead of using Reader::from_file() also use Reader::from_reader() for the file, that is then the same as the response. Also does not work, same compiler error message as in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning `impl SomeTrait` means the function returns *one concrete type* that implements that trait and you just don't want to spell out what type it is. It doesn't mean it can return heterogeneous types.

`Box<dyn BufRead>` is the right choice here:

```rust
use failure::{Error, format_err, ResultExt};  // failure = "0.1.6"
use quick_xml::Reader;  // quick-xml = "0.17.2"
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::path::Path;

/// Returns an XML stream either from a file or a URL.
fn get_xml_stream(source: &str) -> Result<Reader<Box<dyn BufRead>>, Error> {
    let local_path = Path::new(source);

    if local_path.is_file() {
        let file = File::open(local_path)?;
        let reader = BufReader::new(file);

        Ok(Reader::from_reader(Box::new(reader)))
    } else {
        let response = reqwest::get(source).context(format!(
            "File not found and failed fetching from remote URL {}",
            source
        ))?;
        if !response.status().is_success() {
            return Err(format_err!("XML download failed with {:#?}", response));
        }
        let reader = BufReader::new(response);

        Ok(Reader::from_reader(Box::new(reader)))
    }
}
```

As a side note, mixing local path and remote URL is not a good idea. A mere `local_path.is_file()` is not enough to sanitize the input. You've been warned.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! I was close with the Box, but did not get the rewrite to also use from_reader() with the Box for the file :-)

Comment: why not from_file?